# array always returns stupid things

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I don't know why it doesn't work...

I have an array

```
int point[6][6][1]
```

and I have a while loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (point[i + 1][0][0] > 0) {
   i++;
}

return i;
```

If I have 3 points declared

```
point[1][0][0] = 1;
point[2][0][0] = 2;
point[3][0][0] = 3;

TotalNumberOfPoints(point)
```

The while loop ends with `i` being 4.

If I have 4 points declared

```
point[1][0][0] = 1;
point[2][0][0] = 2;
point[3][0][0] = 3;
point[4][0][0] = 4;
```

It returns 4.

If I have 5 points declared

```
point[1][0][0] = 1;
point[2][0][0] = 2;
point[3][0][0] = 3;
point[4][0][0] = 4;
point[5][0][0] = 5;
```

It returns 7.

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you `initialised` the array properly?

Comment: Please consider giving this question a better title.

Comment: This title is quite unhelpful. Please provide a title that is descriptive enough for someone that finds it in search results to get an idea of what is in the question.

Comment: I had to rollback the moderator's edit because it changed essentials of the question.

Comment: Please explain in what way it changed the essentials of the question. (And maybe let me know first.) @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @minitech: you added a semicolon that specified that the array was not initialized. this was not present in the OP's text.

Comment: Could you perhaps have changed, just, you know, the semicolon?

Comment: @minitech: i think you're doing OK now with the edit. just *don't change the code*, or other essentials of a question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I know how to edit properly; isn’t it reasonable to assume that a one-line snippet without a semicolon could just be a typo, especially considering the other ones? I’ll leave it if you think it really makes a difference. It’d be nice if the asker of the question said something…

Comment: (Plus, your answer assumes that it *wasn’t* initialized.)

Comment: @minitech: it is indeed reasonable to assume that it could be a typo. but from there to "correcting" the code is a long jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the array while declaring it

```
int point[6][6][1]={0};
```

Otherwise it will contain garbage value which may not be `zero`, making your loop condition false.

And your loop should be

```
while(i<5 && point[i+1][0][0] > 0) {
   i++;
 }
```

Comment: @user3520616,  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider 
[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some
reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your loop may produce undefined behavior when the last `point` (i.e. the one with the first index of `5` is set, because the loop is not checking `i` for `i < 5`.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
while(i < 5 && point[i + 1][0][0] > 0] {
   i++;
}
```

The reason you compare `i` to 5, not to `6`, is that you proceed to checking `point[i+1]`, so `i` needs to be less than 5, not 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do this

```
while(point[i + 1][0][0] > 0] {
   i++;
}
```

What happens when `i = 6`? You will get undefined behavior. It doesn't know the array just started indexing out of bounds, so the "element at index 7" may very well be greater than 0, or less, or whatever happens to be there.

Also your array is uninitialized so the value at each element may be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to zero-initialize your array.

```
int point[6][6][1] = {};
```

By the way, note that

- For correctness you need to ensure that there's a 0 at the end of the array, *or* stop the looping some other way (e.g. use a counter).
- A dimension of size 1 is not really useful.
- You can use `std::vector` to create a dynamically sized array.